# read_sql and redshift giving error on unicode

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, unicode, amazon-redshift

Query 1: Using pandas read_sql to read from MySQL. The resulting dataframe has a column whose datatype is unicode strings. This column is converted to a tuple and used in the following query.

Query 2: Using pandas read_sql to read from Redshift. The query is something like

```
select b.a from b where b.c in {0}
```

On one string, it gives me an error. The string is like u"Hello 'There" which is a valid unicode string. 
The error is

```
syntax error at or near ""Hello 'There""
```

But it shouldn't take it that way. Its treating it as an empty string ("") followed by un-understandable symbol like (Hello 'There"")

Should some configuration be changed or some parameters in read_sql to be added

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that that error message is being generated by someone replacing a marker (I've used `{something}`) a template like

```
'syntax error at or near "{something}"'
```

This means you should instead see it as a complaint about a single string whose value would appear to be

```
'"Hello \' There"'
```

In other words, it seems likely that you are dealing with a fifteen-character string starting and ending in a double-quote character, though there is always the possibility that some inappropriate conversion or quoting has added the double-quotes. No code, no traceback, so difficult to tell.

It seems as though somewhere in the processing chain there is a failure to correctly handle single apostrophes in SQL string literals. In SQL that string would be correctly represented as

```
'"Hello, ''There"'
```

You will observe that the single-quote embedded in the string had had to be doubled to represent it - the SQL syntax specifically denotes this as the correct way to embed apostrophes in SQL string constants. Since you don't actually show details of your code there is a limit to how helpful this answer can be.

I suspect you might be writing your own SQL, in which case given a query in the variable `sql` you might want to consider using

```
sql.replace("'", "''")
```

as the value injected into the query. But beware all the usual warnings about SQL injection if you plan to incorporate user inputs into this scheme.

Comment: The value isn't `'"Hello, ''There"'` 
it's `"Hello, 'There"` or you could say `'Hello, \'There'`

Comment: And I am using pandas to read the sql not native python way of using it

Comment: in the tuple it can be seen as 
`u"Hello 'There"`